# How to select animation channels using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, dopesheet

How to select channels using python?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`ActionGroup.select`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ActionGroup.html#bpy.types.ActionGroup.select)

[image]

As an example set the "spine" group to selected / unselected from the python console.

```
>>> C.object.animation_data.action.groups['spine'].select = True
```